# How to get initiated in Shaiva Agamas? What to ask and to whom?

Tags: tantra, guru, shaivism, agamas, initiation

I live in New Delhi. Are there any mutt nearby? Regardless of if there are... (I can travel some distance) then what do I tell them? How do I ask? Do I simply say "I want to learn Shaiva Agamas"?
Who should I ask? The mahant or some other person?
Will I have to renounce family?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.